# Trigger to update data in a table relating to multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a school project which use to control stock. I'm trying to update multiple rows in a table using trigger base on 2 more related tables.

So
I have 3 tables as below

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT39N.png)

It's work fine by using trigger event on **StockIn_detail**  for update data in **Products_stock** table

Trigger when insert data:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [StockIn_InsertTrigger]
ON [dbo].[StockIn_Detail]
FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @AmountIn int
DECLARE @WH_ID int

Select @AmountIn=Amount from Inserted
where ProID=(Select ProID from inserted)
-- Base on warehouse
select @WH_ID = wh_id from StockIn where InID = (select InID from inserted)

BEGIN
    Update Products_stock set Qty_on_hand = Qty_on_hand + @AmountIn where product_id = (Select ProID from inserted)
    and warehouse_id = @WH_ID
END
```

But when it comes to updating data in **StockIn** table. For example when I want to change the warehouse(wh_id) to other warehouses. In this situation, I must update **Products_stock** table by subtracting the product's quantity_on_hand in old warehouse then add it back to the new warehouse. It's hard to explain because of my poor English, So this is my code in **StockIn** trigger update event which I tried but failed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [UpdateWHStockIn]
ON [dbo].[StockIn]
FOR UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @OldWH int, @NewWH int, @TID nvarchar(50)
SELECT @TID = InID FROM deleted
SELECT @OldWH = wh_id  FROM deleted
SELECT @NewWH = wh_id FROM inserted

DECLARE @InTbl table (ProductID nvarchar(5), Amount int, OldWH int, NewWH int)
INSERT INTO @InTbl (ProductID, Amount) 
            SELECT ProID, Amount FROM StockIn_Detail WHERE StockIn_Detail.InID = @TID 
BEGIN
    -- Update only when warehouse change 
    if @OldWH <> @NewWH
    begin
    -- Subtract stock which use old warehouse id
    UPDATE Products_stock
    SET Qty_on_hand = Qty_on_hand - (SELECT Amount FROM @InTbl)
    WHERE product_id IN (SELECT ProductID  FROM @InTbl) 
    AND warehouse_id = @OldWH

    -- add to stock which use new warehouse id
    UPDATE Products_stock
    SET Qty_on_hand = Qty_on_hand + (SELECT Amount FROM @InTbl)
    WHERE product_id IN (SELECT ProductID  FROM @InTbl) 
    AND warehouse_id = @NewWH

    end
END
```

**Error:**
Subquery return more than 1 value

I know it cause by using subquery in a wrong ways, but I cannot find solutions because I am new to sql as I'm a college student. I can solve this problem if I use C# program which I know better by loop , declare variable, compare it, and update eachrow... but I think it's not a best practice to write loop like this and also create function outside sql server also my concern. This might cause wrong data if I forgot to use that function in c# code somewhere unlike trigger which occur everytime I update data. So I don't need to worry about writing it again and again.

Comment: Your first problem is the assumption that a trigger fires _per row_. It doesn't. And when an insert or an update affects multiple rows, your trigger will process one arbitrary row from the operation, and won't tell you that it ignored the rest. See [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers).

Comment: I got it. Thank you for sharing